# Monitoring background tasks on a scaled environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, cloud, background-process, scaling

We have an on-premise solution (c#.net) which is working fine, now we are trying to migrate to cloud(azure) to utilize the auto-scaling feature.

we faced a few issues, one of them is the background tasks monitoring.

We create a new long-running task as the following:

```
1- Write the C# code that will be run on background
2- Run it using our own JobFramework in another thread and storing some handle for the running task
3- Keep checking the progress of the task using the handle
```

Now let's suppose that we got 2 instances after the scaling and the 1st one runs some task.

If the user check the status of the task using the handle and the request went to the 2nd machine we will get unexpected result because it's running on some thread at the 1st machine.

Is there any suggestion to solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifics; here I go.

This is a classic scale up issue (multiple instances behind a load balancer etc.). Basically for any request that depends on state of other running etc. you need to sync them up. This is same problem as multiple instances talking to same database hence lock etc. to be handled.

I would handle this by maintaining status in a common place outside of instances. In fact you could even use a common database or cache end point to maintain state and simulate your own lock etc.

Another way could be maintaining a message queue like SQS outside of the instances and instances need to smartly pick up work but this could be a major change so may not be easy to implement.